# Laravel Handle big web application like amazon?

Tags: php, laravel-5, yaf-php-framework

I want to start a big level E-commerce project like (amazon.com) in laravel 5.3.
But I confused before starting about many topics

```
1: Can laravel handle big level project like amazone.com big store.
2: Laravel secure  
3: laravel handle millions or records 
4: performance?
```

Thats laravel is good for big level project or not?

Comment: Laravel can definitely be highly optimized, but Laravel is just a framework.  How you code with it and the utilities you use along with it are going to be the major factors, like caching, the database setup, load balancing, etc.    No major site out there relies on one tool or one language to run their site.

Comment: if we compare laravel with other frame work then ?

Comment: Don't get hung up on a framework for performance.  Use what your development team is comfortable with, if and when you get to a point when you're comparable to Amazon, then you can spend extra time into optimization of the code.

Comment: right buddy its mean coding style and optimization matter not framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a site, https://stackshare.io/, that provides information about companies and its technologies. Also, it offers users to point out and vote on the best aspects of and certain tool.

Lets use this site data to compare Laravel, Sympony, CakePHP and Zend Framework

---

### Laravel

https://stackshare.io/laravel

Has **1520 Votes**, the most quantity of votes goes for:

- Clean architecture (228)
- Growing community (180)
- Composer friendly (177)
- Open source (155)
- The only framework to consider for php (142)

Its **used by 1100** companies

It **integrates 10** other tools, the top 3 are:

- Auth0
- KeyCDN
- Rollbar

---

### Symfony

https://stackshare.io/symfony

Has **535 Votes**, the most quantity of votes goes for:

- Open source (94)
- Php (74)
- Community (67)
- Dependency injection (63)
- Professional (55)

Its **used by 492** companies

It **integrates 4** other tools, the top 3 are:

- Auth0
- fortrabbit
- Logmatic

---

### CakePHP

https://stackshare.io/cakephp

Has **43 Votes**, the most quantity of votes goes for:

- Open source (23)
- Really rapid framework (9)
- Good code organization (3)
- Security best practices (3)
- Flexibility (3)

Its **used by 125** companies

It **integrates 3** other tools, the top 3 are:

- Auth0
- Raygun
- PHP (This doesn't count, I guess)

---

### Zend Framework

https://stackshare.io/zend-framework

Has **21 Votes**, the most quantity of votes goes for:

- Open source (14)
- Community (7)

Its **used by 87** companies

It **integrates 2** other tools, the top 2 are:

- KeyCDN
- PHP (This doesn't count, I guess)

---

**Analysis**

Laravel seems to be the "framework of the moment", its the most used and voted up, also has the major quantity of integrations.
The others come just in this order: Symfony, CakePHP and Zend Framework. Its hard to tell based only on this site data, Zend is a wonderfull framework, but its not easy to learn, so people tend to avoid it. I can't tell much about CakePHP and Symfony as I never worked with it. One can see these results and think: "Oh, Zend is the worst!", well, framework choice tend to be a trend. All these 4 frameworks are really good, but Laravel is in the top of mind, you will read about it much more than the others. Is Zend less secure than Laravel? I doubt, security is much far from the framework, it goes to your server as a whole. All these 4 are secure, all these 4 offers good stability and performance.

We can't tell much using only one source of data (there are others sites that provide stacks about tools and companies). I just wanted to show you that frameworks are chosen by the taste of developers.